# Alternate projections in shader

Tags: shader, projections, matrix

I have a projection calculation which maps points from 3D space to pixel (image) space, and I want to use it as instead of the standard MVP projections in a vertex shader.

In the image below the lower blue flow is how I understand the pipeline works in GLSL, and the upper green arc is what I want to use instead.
[image]

Since GLSL's projection matrix doesn't produce pixel coordinates, but a homogenous vec4 that allows to calculate pixel coords and depth estimation, I need to make some adjustments:

My idea is to take the vec2 pixel coordinates from my calculation, map them to clip space and let openGL finish the conversion to pixel space by itself

[image]

Only problem is I'm not entirely sure how to pull this off, as you can see Im missing some essential data about what happens after Clip space

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
The GLSL implementation of the 3D to 2D projection function can be found here
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/fltfW2

Comment: Can you add some information about the way you calculate the pixel position?

Comment: At the first "???" there the 4D vector will be divided by its "w" component. The geometry will be clipped to range [-1, 1] in all dimensions (z value range can be clipped on a different range depending on the graphics library you are using)....

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thanks for helping!

Unfortunately I cannot disclose the calculations or matrices but I can say its been tested to take a point in 3D space and return it's projected 2D pixel coordinate (image / screen size is taken into account of course).
it has been tested both in python and in GLSL (shadertoy)

Comment: when having a triangle (3 vertices) is the surface spanning this triangle a triangle in your calculated space as well?

Comment: the relationship between the vertices doesn't change so a triangle will remain a triangle.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I edited the post and added a link to shadertoy where I have the GLSL implementation: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/fltfW2